# How to start Linux applications automatically start on Chromebook

Tags: linux, boot, google-chrome, chromebook, google-chrome-os

I hope that maybe someone has tried it, maybe there is someone who has experience in Linux, maybe there is also someone who has experience in Chromebook

Please, all the answers and suggestions here are really appreciated, please help me

Comment: Clarify if you mean (a) startup of system, or (b) login by user.